# Why doesn't my code enter for loop when record found?

Tags: apex, soql, loop, after-trigger

I have an object(Huishouden__c) with a related list. I loop trough the object records with a for loop on the related record. When I debug the object in the first loop I get an Id but it does not enter the second loop?

```
[SELECT id FROM Huishouden__c WHERE id IN : uniqueHuish]
```

This returns an Id, I doent see any errors in my debug

Loops:

```
 List<Huishouden__c> deleteHuish = new List<Huishouden__c>(); 
    for(Huishouden__c h: [SELECT id FROM Huishouden__c 
                          WHERE id IN : uniqueHuish]) {
                              system.debug('SELECT id FROM Huishouden__c'+ [SELECT id FROM Huishouden__c WHERE id IN : uniqueHuish]);
                              for(Relatie__c rc : h.Relatie_Contacten__r) { 
                                  system.debug('h'+h);
                                   system.debug('h.Relatie_Contacten__r'+h.Relatie_Contacten__r);
                                  if(h.Relatie_Contacten__r.size()<=1) {
                                      deleteHuish.add(h);   
                                  }  
                              }
                          }
    delete deleteHuish;
    system.debug('deleteHuish '+deleteHuish);
```

Comment: Don't you need to query for child records in the first SOQL for loop? Like - SELECT id,(Select id from Relatie_Contacten__r) FROM Huishouden__c 
                          WHERE id IN : uniqueHuish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, you need to execute a SOQL to fetch the child records which you are not doing currently. Thats why it is not entering inner `for` loop.

Since, you are checking the count and trying to delete records, you can follow this most optimized approach.

Prepare an Aggregate query like this and execute the `delete` operation. Be sure to verify the related parent field (e.g. `Huishouden__c` ) from child object `Relatie__c` based on which you will be grouping the records.

```
List<Huishouden__c> deleteHuish = new List<Huishouden__c>(); 
List<AggregateResult> results = [SELECT Huishouden__c, COUNT(Id) idCount
                                    FROM Relatie__c
                                    WHERE Huishouden__c IN:uniqueHuish
                                    GROUP BY Huishouden__c
                                    HAVING COUNT(Id) <2];

for(AggregateResult result: results)
{
    Huishouden__c obj = new Huishouden__c(Id = (String) result.get('Huishouden__c'));
    deleteHuish.add(obj);
}
delete deleteHuish;
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the count part before in subquery which didnt work, but figured out now what was wrong with my annotation.

Comment: for this kind of use case prefer to use `Aggregate` query